# Is a kohen's grandson a kohen?

Tags: kohen-priest, family-members

My father was a kohen. Is my son, his grandson, a kohen? There are no other grandchildren in our family.

Comment: Are you a boy or a girl? Kohein-ness is passed on paternally and only in the case where the Kohein married [someone permitted to him.](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/468267/jewish/Kohen-Marriages.htm)

Comment: I'm sorry for your loss. May God comfort you among all the others who mourn for Jerusalem.

Answer (score 4):

A man who was born a *kohen* passes that to his son (and he to his son, and so on). It doesn't pass through a daughter to a grandson. The only exception is that it (generally) doesn't pass to a son who's the offspring of the *kohen* and someone forbidden to him (including a gentile woman).

As a source and for more info, see [`http://chabad.org/468267`](http://chabad.org/468267). Hat tip to [Double AA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa) for the URL.